# Filtering by a subtotal of the measure

Tags: mdx

I have the following query in MDX:

```
SELECT {

    [Season].[Season].members *
    [Measures].[Wins]

} ON COLUMNS, {

    Filter([Team].[Name].[Name].members, [Measures].[Wins] > 100)

} ON ROWS

FROM [Nfl2]
```

[image]

Here I am filtering by "All Wins > 100". How would I filter by "Wins in 2012 > 10" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code :

```
SELECT {

    [Season].[Season].members *
    [Measures].[Wins]

} ON COLUMNS, {

    Filter([Team].[Name].[Name].members, ([Season].[Season].&[2012],[Measures].[Wins]) > 100)

} ON ROWS

FROM [Nfl2]
```